# How to connect DB2 with eclipse on mac?

Tags: db2, java, jdbc, mac-os-x

I tried to connect the DB2 Express-C Version 10.1 to Eclipse Mars but it returns an exception when I tried to run the program.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException:
Error opening socket to server localhost/127.0.0.1 on port 50,000 with message
Connection refused. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
```

I think there is an issue with the port number or connection url.

OS: Mac OS X El Capitan

Eclipse: Eclipse Mars

DB: DB2 Express-C 10.1

Comment: TCP/IP service enabled? Firewall ok? DB2 actuall up & running?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to follow the Network Access steps from the [DB2 on Mac OS X install guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797):

> Network access
>
> The instructions below assume that you installed DB2 with your current
>   user account. If you manually created a different account such as
>   "db2inst1", replace `$(whoami)` with `db2inst1`
>
> If you need to access this DB2 instance remotely, you should configure
>   the service:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using svcename db2c_$(whoami)

sudo su -
echo "db2c_$(whoami) 50000/tcp" >> /etc/services 
exit

db2set -all db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP 
db2stop force 
db2start
```

Alternately, instead of keeping the local DB2 Express-C install, you can run [DB2 in a Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2express-c/).